# How can I create a unit test that verifies that all fluent validators can be resolved by Windsor?

Tags: c#, generics, castle-windsor

I am using [FluentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) in my application to verify my entities, but I have come up with a little issue.  My validation factory is setup to resolve validation classes from Windsor by attempting to resolve from the `IValidator<EntityType>` interface.

I want to make sure that whenever a validation class is creating that no one forgets to register it with Windsor.

Essentially I want to look at all classes in the assembly that implement the `IValidator<EntityType>` interface and call `WindsorContainer.Resolve(typeof(IValidator<EntityType>))` to resolve that type, where `EntityType` can be any class in the assembly.  So far, using reflection I have been able to pull out all classes that are derived from the generic interface `IValidator<>` but I can't figure out how to proceed from there.  The problem is I would have to find some way to pull out the actual entity used in the generic in order to call Windsor correctly, and I am at a loss of how to do that.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to make sure that whenever a validation class is creating that no one forgets to register it with Windsor.

Why are you doing this? You should have an [installer](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Installers.ashx) that automatically discovers these validation classes and registers them for you. Then you only need to test that you coded the installer correctly.

The fact that someone adds a class that implements `IValidator<TEntity>` for some `TEntity` shouldn't break your code!

> The problem is I would have to find some way to pull out the actual entity used in the generic in order to call Windsor correctly, and I am at a loss of how to do that.

You want [`Type.GetGenericArguments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx).

Comment: But how do I test that the installer is finding and registering them all correctly?

Comment: @KallDrexx: The method you described is fine. The answer to how to do that is to use `Type.GetGenericArguments` so that you can extract the entity type.

Comment: Aha perfect.  I did intend to have an installer register the validators automatically, I guess I worded that initial part you quoted badly.  Thanks :)